# Jmeter Beanshell get value from JSON Extractor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I use JSON Extractor to get value from respond body.
Then I want to get this value for Authorization to add to header to use for next http request .
How can I get this value in Beanshell?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf9cS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEugp.png)

Answer (score 0):

In general there is `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides read/write access to [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so change your `$.api_token` to `vars.get("api_token")` and that would be it.

However there are some problems with your script:

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as [Groovy provides much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) (and has better Java support and [extra set of features on top of Java SDK](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html))
2. You don't need scripting at all, you can create the header using JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

   [image]